# How difficult is it to get a key using simple XOR

Tags: encryption

Recently someone gave me an algorithm as follows:

XOR = Key XOR Random1 XOR Random2.

They think that in order for someone to extract "Key" from XOR they would need Random1 and Random2.. but looking at the above algorithm, i think it should be fairly easy for someone to guess or extract the Key w/o Random1 and Random2. The data is just 256 bits long.

Thoughts?

Comment: If even one of the Random's is really fully random, not known to any attacker, as long as the key and not used anywhere else, it is impossible to get the key for any attacker. That's called a one-time pad and is the only cryptographic algorithm to be known as fully secure against any attack (as long as the mentioned things hold true).

Comment: ["Only" 256 bits long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem).

Answer (score 4):

That "algorithm" is fine, as long as the random values cannot be guessed by an attacker. The scheme is known as (trivial) [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing).

XOR with completely random data is called a one time pad or OTP. The security of the algorithm therefore depends on the random number generator. Of course there are additional operational requirements to obtain system security (if somebody just distributes his share of the key ...).

Comment: Even more precisely, that "algorithm" is fine if and only if: for each of the 256 bit ranks, the bit of that rank in at least one of the random values cannot be guessed by an attacker.

Comment: Also don't forget random 1 and random 2 cannot be equal. come to think of it the more those overlap the more of the plain text would be visible?

Comment: That should not be a problem as long as the partial keys are generated using a secure PRNG. The chances of the random values being equal are 1 / 2^256, so the same goes for the full key being the same as one of the partial keys (for a setup with 3 parties).

Comment: I'd be much much more worried about the sun exploding some billions of years earlier than we expect than about truly random 256 bit strings being equal.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson You'll be happy to know that the Sun will not explode, and instead roast us ("us" as in "our atoms") when it becomes a red giant :)